# Unpacking values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

It might be a basic question but what does `line, =` in the below code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)

plt.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )

plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

I tried with a simple example `a, = 1` which throws the error `int` object is not iterable, and this `a, = 1,` works.

So what does **`var, =`** does?

Comment: I'm curious, what do you get from `print(line)` after `line, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)`. I can't test atm but I wasn't aware that `plot()` returned anything.

Comment: @roganjosh Full reference [adding text](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#annotating-text)

Comment: @roganjosh it return a Line2D object `Line2D(_line0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)` returns a `tuple` with *one* `element`. This is then unpacked into a `variable`: `line`.

The same logic can be seen here:

```
>>> a = tuple([1])
>>> a
(1,)
>>> b, = a
>>> b
1
```

Comment: Oh! looks like a tuple for single element.

Comment: @bhansa Yes, exactly! I tried to show that in my answer, may not have been clear though...